# Convert a User Entered Date with JSON mm/dd/yyyy Format and Display It as a Result

Tags: javascript, html, json, css

```js
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("textbox").value = " ";
}

/*
var dateString = "\/Date(1334514600000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString ));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year; 
*/

var request;
var date;
function getUserRequest() {
    return document.getElementById("request_input").value;
}
function getUserDate() {
    return document.getElementById("date_input").value;
}
function display() {
    request = getUserRequest();
    date = getUserDate();
    document.getElementById("textbox").value = date + " - " + request;
}
```

```css
body  {
    
  background-color:#f5f5dc;
  padding-left:100px; 
  padding-right:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;

  }

form  {
  outline-offset:12px;
     outline-color:red;
  outline-width:3px;
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color:#008080;
  }

h2  {
 color:#00cc00;
 text-align:left;
 }

p  {
 color:blue;
 text-align:left;
 }
textarea  {
   margin-left:430px
   }


#clearbutton  {
    text-align:left;
    }

#submit   {
    text-align:left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <html lang="en">
  <title>Project 4</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project4css.css">
  <script src="project4js.js"></script>

</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<form id='form' name="form1" method = 'post'>
    
    <h2>Change and Update Packages</h2>


    <textarea id="textbox" rows="10" cols="50">

    </textarea>


    <p>Enter Your Request:</p>
    <input type="text" id="request_input" name="request">

    <p>Request Date:</p>
    <input type="text" id="date_input" name="date">

<br>
<br>
<br>

    <input id ="submit" type = "button" onclick="display()" value='Add Request'/>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input id="clear_button" type="button" name="clearbutton" value="Clear Request" onclick="javascript:eraseText();"> 

</form>



</body>

</html>
```

- When a user enters a date like so: 12/25/2016 it will be converted into this type of format: **Mon Dec 25 2016**.  I have the functionality working with javascript being displayed in the textbox but no conversion is happening at the moment. I have the JSON there but don't know how to utilize it.

Expand the snippet to fix the textbox.

Comment: because no where in the functions you are calling the conversion functions. Probably you have commented it

Comment: have you try with `toUTCString()`  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp

Comment: I have the date string being parsed I am just curious how do I get it work with a entered user date.

Comment: input `type="date"` is more use full

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use with [input type="date"](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)  and [toUTCString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp) .

```js
function check(){
  var dates = document.getElementById('date').value;
  console.log(new Date(dates).toUTCString())
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" onchange="check()">check me
```

***Update answer with Json***

```js
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("textbox").value = " ";
}

function display() {
     var request = document.getElementById("request_input").value;
     var dates = document.getElementById("date_input").value;
       var d=new Date(dates);
  var date_array=  '{"test_day":"'+d.getDay()+'","test_date":"'+d.getDate()+'","test_month":"'+d.getMonth()+'", "test_year":"'+d.getFullYear()+'","test_utc":"'+d.toUTCString()+'"}';
  var obj = JSON.parse(date_array);
  document.getElementById("textbox").value = obj.test_utc +'-'+request;
  console.log(obj)
    
}
```

```css
body  {
    
  background-color:#f5f5dc;
  padding-left:100px; 
  padding-right:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;

  }

form  {
  outline-offset:12px;
     outline-color:red;
  outline-width:3px;
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color:#008080;
  }

h2  {
 color:#00cc00;
 text-align:left;
 }

p  {
 color:blue;
 text-align:left;
 }
textarea  {
   margin-left:430px
   }


#clearbutton  {
    text-align:left;
    }

#submit   {
    text-align:left;
    }
```

```html
<form id='form' name="form1" method = 'post'>
    <h2>Change and Update Packages</h2>
  <textarea id="textbox" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <p>Enter Your Request:</p>
    <input type="text" id="request_input" name="request">
<p>Request Date:</p>
    <input type="date" id="date_input" name="date">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input id ="submit" type = "button" onclick="display()" value='Add Request'/>
<br>
 <br>
  <input id="clear_button" type="button" name="clearbutton" value="Clear Request" onclick="javascript:eraseText();"> 
</form>
```

Comment: how do I get the dates to display in my text box?

Comment: See the updated answer I was added  result with in textbox

Comment: very clear explanation. thanks.  I had date input type before but I swapped it back to text for testing.

Comment: if you need ah date value as a string like `month ,date ,year` right

Comment: is there a way to use JSON and get the same result?

Comment: See the updated answer.I was update with json object .If get the month,date,year from json example `date` apply `obj.test_date`

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment this on the other answer but using `<input type="date">` will not work with other browsers aside from Chrome and Firefox.

You can instead use Date.parse()